# GWT Cell Tree - leaf nodes

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm using a cell tree and I have this problem:
I get the data via RPC calls. I decide if a node is a leaf or not - based on the data that I get for its children. For example - if a node has a son called "foo" - then this node should be a leaf.
I don't know how to make this node to be a leaf and not to show its children on the tree.   (instead, I want to show them somewhere else, when clicking on the node)
Is it possible? Does anyone have an idea?
Please help me, I'm stuck with it for 2 days...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can override isLeaf() method to return true or false.

There will be a problem, however, from the UI perspective. Before a user clicks on a node, you don't know if this should be a node or a leaf. This is a little confusing, although I saw such implementations more than once. If your tree is not very large, consider loading all data at once, and then building it the way you want - creating nodes or leafs as necessary.

Comment: I get the children for a node using AsyncDataProvider. In getNodeInfo() I'm creating a new instance of the data provider. In the onRangeChanged() of the data provider I call the callback method, and in its onSuccess method I update the data. I can check the result of onSuccess - if it has "foo" and then return Null, meaning this node has no children, but then when clicking on the node it throws a Null exception. Now, if I don't return Null - then it shows the children. And I can't find a way to check the children from the CustomTreeModel!

Comment: I changed my answer following these details.

Comment: My tree is very large, so I can't load all the data at once. I don't see how I can use the isLeaf method here. How can I check in this method the list of the dataProvider? The only access to the values of the list is from the render() method that I implement when creating a cell, but I don't see how it can help me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If each node has a type, could you create some list or map of types that aren't expected to have children in your TreeViewModel impl?

In an impl I did I used a meta-model for all types, but it's not a requirement.

E.g.,

```
@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
boolean result = true;
if (value == null) {
    result = false;  // assumes all root nodes have children
} else if (value instanceof NavNode) {
    final NavNode currentNode = (NavNode) value;
    final NodeType currentNodeType = NodeType.fromValue(currentNode.getType());
    if (currentNode.hasChildren() || NodeHelper.couldHaveChildren(currentNodeType)) {
        result = false;
    }
}
return result;
```

}

```
// Create a data provider for root nodes
protected ListDataProvider<NavNode> getDataProvider(Collection<NavNode> rootNodes) {
return new ListDataProvider<NavNode>(new LinkedList<NavNode>(rootNodes));
```

}

```
// Create a data provider that contains the    immediate descendants.
protected AsyncDataProvider<NavNode> getDataProvider(final NavNode node) {
return new AsyncDataProvider<NavNode>() {
    @Override
    protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<NavNode> display) {
        final Set<NavNode> clientNodes = util.getAncestorNodes(node);
        clientNodes.add(node);
        final NavigationInfo clientInfo = new NavigationInfo(clientNodes);
        navigationService.getNavInfo(clientInfo, node, resources, qualifications, new SafeOperationCallback<NavigationInfo>(eventBus, false) {

            @Override
            public void onFailureImpl(Throwable caught) {
                GWT.log("Something went wrong retreiving children for " + node.getName(), caught);
                updateRowCount(0, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccessImpl(OperationResult<NavigationInfo> or) {
                util.mergeNavInfo(or.getResult());
                final NavNode nodeFromServer = util.getNode(node.getId());
                final Range range = display.getVisibleRange();
                final int start = range.getStart();
                final Set<NavNode> nodes = util.getNodes(nodeFromServer.getChildren());
                updateRowData(display, start, new LinkedList<NavNode>(nodes));
            }

        });

    }
};
```

}

```
private static class NodeHelper {

private static final Set<NodeType> PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES;

static {
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES = new HashSet<NodeType>();
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.ASSET_OWNER);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.OPERATING_DAY);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.RESOURCES);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.RESOURCE);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.ENERGY);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.RESERVE);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.DAY_AHEAD_CLEARED_OFFERS);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.DRR_LOAD_FORCAST);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.RESERVE_DISPATCH);
    PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.add(NodeType.RESERVE_RAMP_RATE);
}

public static boolean couldHaveChildren(NodeType nodeType) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (PARENTAL_NODE_TYPES.contains(nodeType)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Well, my problem is that I don't know in advance if a specific node is going to be a parent or not. I can have 2 nodes of the same type, in the same level, that after clicking on them - both will have list of children, but one of the lists will contain the word "foo" (for example), and therefore I would like its parent to be a leaf, and when clicking on this leaf node - to see its list of children somewhere else on the screen. But I understand now that this isn't possible, since when clicking on these two nodes' parent- it should already be clear if they are leaves or not(for the open icon).